# Highlight issues with %d in the datetime format

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

As shown in the screenshot below, %d is being highlighted orange when it is a a part of a datetime format string.

[image: datetime format highlight issue]

I've tried modifying the color manually using the scopes shown below. However, the color does not change unless I modify "source.python constant" which also changes the color of other elements.

[image: %d textmate scopes]

Does anyone have any suggestions for fixing this issue? The only post I could find describing this issue was [this github thread](https://github.com/MagicStack/MagicPython/issues/106), but modifying those scopes does not appear to solve the issue. Here's my current setup:

- **Editor name and version**: VSCode 1.55.2
- **Platform**: MacOS
- **Color scheme**: Atom One Dark

Comment: the language server does not know it is a date format string, and `%d` in strings is often used to format numbers, probably `%f` will also be colored different

Comment: That's correct, but with the introduction of f-strings this no longer seems necessary. However, targeting highlighting through the "meta.format.percent.python" does nothing.

Comment: but there are other methods to format stuff and they use `%d`, and these are not deprecated and will never be deprecated

Comment: Makes sense but do you see any way to disable the highlighting with the scopes provided in the github thread?

Comment: then customize the color with the correct TextMate scope to the green color for this theme